# Can we have any plugin by which we can add re-run button on jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for some kind of plugin or some kind of workaround by which i can have a button to rerun a build with same parameters on console page . so we can directly click and a new build will run without passing new params.

I tried some searches but not able to find this kind of plugin.

Comment: Do you use pipeline jobs? If so, a 'replay' button should be available when focusing on a specific build. It should use the same parameters which where passed in your specific build you are focusing from.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Unforgettable631 No i am not using pipeline job. Its just a maven project job.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found which is helping me.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin